# How to split string by string (multi-character) separator into an array?

Tags: bash, string, array

Basically I'd like to split a string into an array by a string separator like `sep.` for example.
Is there native `bash` way to do this without using tools like `sed`, `awk`, etc?
I know I can split a string into an array by setting `IFS` and  using `read -ra` but that doesn't work with string separators. And if there is not how you'd do it with tools like `sed`, `awk`, etc?

Let's say I have the string `This is some sep.string` and I'd like to split it into an array with 2 elements: `This is some` and `string`.

Comment: There may actually some way to do that directly, but you could just replace the multi-character separator with a character which doesn't appear in the string: `foo='a sep b sep c'; s=$'\1'; IFS=$s read -ra <<<"${foo//sep/$s}" array; printf "{%s}\n" "${array[@]}"`

Comment: Will your array ever have more than two elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could manually iterate through the variable with parameter expansion:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
var='This is some sep.string
with
newlines
sep.another line'

a=()
while [[ $var =~ sep\. ]]
do
  e=${var%%sep.*}
  a+=("${e}")
  var=${var#${e}sep.}
done
a+=("${var}")
```

This loops over the variable (updating it in the process), stripping off the first separator onwards (`%%` looks for the longest match, so this will track backwards from the end of the string until the first instance of `sep.`); it adds that remainder into the array then strips that remainder and the separator off from the front of the variable. Iterate until the variable does not contain a separator any more, then add any remainder into the array.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of a native way to do it using both parameter expansion and readarray

```
string='This is some sep.string'
mapfile -t array < <( echo "${string//sep./$'\n'}" )
```

`${string//sep./$'\n'}` - Will replace occurrences of `sep.` with a newline.
`mapfile`/`readarray` will create an array with each line in it's own element.